# HTML Canvas arc method doesn't line up curves

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**UPDATE**
I've just realised that this is only happening in Chrome, so I guess that this is a browser issue rather than a programming issue?

I'm drawing a circle that needs to be split into clickable sections using the HTML5 Canvas.

The circle itself is an image that I'm importing, and then I create 22 equally split sections using the arc method:

```
var segments = 22;
var segment = (2 * Math.PI) / segments

can = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = can.getContext('2d');

ctx.strokeStyle = '#666';
ctx.fillStyle = '#ff9';

for (var i = 0; i < (segments); i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc((can.width / 2), can.height / 2, can.width / 2, segment * i, segment * (i+1), false);
    ctx.lineTo(can.width / 2, can.height / 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

I can get it to work fine, but the edges of the curve don't lie up with the adjacent arc properly.

I've created a fiddle of the above to show the issue http://jsfiddle.net/4sARr/.

How can I get the stop points to line up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I discovered in the update, Chrome is the culprit.
Version 31 doesn't seem to be calculating the arc correctly - but 32 beta and 33 dev builds create correctly shaped arcs.